# Logically Predicting $f^7(x)$ based on $f(x)$

Tags: functions

Say $f(x)=\dfrac{3x+1}{2}$

$f(f(x))=f^2(x)= \dfrac{3(\frac{3x+1}{2})+1}{2} =
\dfrac{9x+5}{4}$

$f(f(f(x)))=f^3(x)=
\dfrac{27x+19}{8}$

I want to predict $f^7(x)$ without manually calculating $f^4(x)$,$f^5(x)$,$f^6(x)$

I clearly can see that
$f^n(x)= \dfrac{3^n+something}{2^n}$

How do I find that $something $?

Comment: Note: check my edit to your post; you don't need so many dollar signs, just at the start of, and end of, an entire mathematical expression.

Comment: thank @amWhy . That will save me lot of time :)

Comment: there is a typo because actually $f^2(x)=\frac{9x+5}{4}$

Comment: extremely sorry, corrected.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

$$
f(x) = \frac{a x+1}{b}\\
f^2(x) = \frac{a^2x + \frac{a^2-b^2}{a-b}}{b^2}\\
\vdots\\
f^n(x) = \frac{a^nx + \frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}}{b^n}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's solve $f(x)=x$:
$$\frac{3x+1}{2}=x$$
$$3x+1=2x$$
$$x=-1$$
So
$$f(-1)=-1$$
This means that
$$f^2(-1)=f(f(-1))=f(-1)=-1$$
and so on.
So based on your conjecture:
$$f^n(x)=\frac{3^nx+c(n)}{2^n}$$
Implies that
$$\frac{-3^n+c(n)}{2^n}=-1$$
$$-3^n+c(n)=-2^n$$
$$c(n)=3^n-2^n$$
So
$$f^n(x)=\frac{3^nx+(3^n-2^n)}{2^n}$$
And why is your conjecture true?
Because
$$f(x)=\frac{3}{2}x+c_1$$
$$f^2(x)=\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{3}{2}x+c_1\right)+c_1=\frac{3^2}{2^2}x+c_2$$
$$f^3(x)=\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{3^2}{2^2}x+c_2\right)+c_1=\frac{3^3}{2^3}x+c_3$$
and so on.

Answer (score 1):

We guess that $$f_n(x)={3^n\cdot x+3^n-2^n\over 2^n}$$to prove that using induction we have  $$f_{n+1}(x)={f(f_n(x))}={3f_n(x)+1\over 2}={3^{n+1}\cdot x+3^{n+1}-3\cdot 2^n+2^n\over 2^{n+1} }={3^{n+1}x+3^{n+1}-2^{n+1}\over 2^{n+1}}$$since $f_1(x)={3x+1\over 2}$ the proof is complete.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:  $$f^n(x) = \frac{3^nx+something}{2^n}$$

Do you notice any pattern for $2^n+something$? Notice that you get

$$f(x) = \frac{3x+1}{2} \implies 1+2 = ?$$

$$f^2(x) = \frac{9x+5}{4} \implies 5+4 = ?$$